# Python command history not working in PowerShell, Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, powershell, cmd

I have a problem with my code. I made a restart function,

```
def restart():
    print('\nReloading...')
    sleep(1)
    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        try:
           os.system('python .\console.py')
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
           exit(0)
    elif sys.platform == 'linux':
        try:
           os.system(py_ver + ' console.py')
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
           exit(0)
    exit(0)
```

it works fine and restarts my `console.py` script but there is one problem. If I hit the `Up-Arrow` or `Down-Arrow` key, in the restarted script, it does nothing in PowerShell but in CMD it works fine. Does anyone know why?
I tried it with a `main()` function but that doesn't really restart the script and I want to be able to do that, I also tried `os.exec*()` but that messes up everything.

Here is the complete code of my `console.py`: [Console.py-GitHub](https://github.com/JuicyMilk/PYDB/blob/master/src/console.py) (if there is a problem with this link got to `src/console.py`)

Some information: Python3.9.0 64-Bit, Windows 10 64-Bit

I appreciate every answer!
Thanks in advance.